# Force ng-repeat to rerun function in data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using `ng-repeat` in a table to show a list of items and their prices.

- The price is bound to `itemPrice(item)`, defined in my controller.
- The function calculates a price based on `$scope.orderType`.
- `orderType` is bound to a `select` in HTML.

**What is the best way to force all prices to update when the order type is changed?**

## HTML

```
<select ng-model="orderType" ng-options="name for name in orderTypes"></select>

<!-- ... -->

<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.is_used"></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="item.quantity" min="0" max="100"></td>
    <td>{{ itemPrice(item) | currency:"$" }}</td>
    <td>{{ itemPrice(item) * item.quantity | currency:"$" }}</td>
</tr>
```

## JavaScript

```
.controller('OrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    
    // Set up order types
    $scope.orderTypes = ['Buy Back', 'Sale'];
    $scope.orderType = $scope.orderTypes[1];

    // ...
    
    // Get the price of an item
    $scope.itemPrice = function(item) {
        if ($scope.orderType === 0) {
            return item.price_buy_back;
        } else if (item.is_used) {
            return item.price_used;
        } else {
            return item.price_new;
        }
    }
    
    // ...
    
}]);
```

Comment: Attach a `ng-change` event to your select, this will run a $digest cycle and your `ng-repeat` will re-bind to `items` (although it should be updating already since you have a `model` bound to it...)

Comment: I added an `ng-change` that calls a function to log `$scope.orderType` to the console. It does log the right order type when the value changes, but the prices still don't update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel silly. I thought I could chalk up the problem to being a newbie at Angular, but the mistake was in plain old JavaScript.

The first line of the `itemPrice` function compares `$scope.orderType` to an integer. But `$scope.orderType` is set to a *string* earlier in the function (`$scope.orderType = $scope.orderTypes[0]`).

Now that the comparison is fixed, `ng-repeat` updates as expected, calling `itemPrice` whenever `$scope.orderType` is changed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm work and I don't really have time to do a plunker to validate this:

I would suggest to not use a function ("itemPrice"). Have this calculated before hand and put the value in a variable within your item structure.

When the other type changes (using ng-change or on $scope.$watch..) then do the recalculation and update the variables within your item structure.

Something like:

```
.controller('OrderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    // Set up order types
    $scope.orderTypes = ['Buy Back', 'Sale'];
    $scope.orderType = $scope.orderTypes[1];

    var itemPrice = function(item) {
        if ($scope.orderType === 0) {
            return item.price_buy_back;
        } else if (item.is_used) {
            return item.price_used;
        } else {
            return item.price_new;
        }
    }

    var setItemPrices = function(){

        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++)
        {
            $scope.items[i].itemPrice = itemPrice($scope.items[i]);
        }
    }

    $scope.$watch("orderType", function(newVal, oldVal){
           //update itemPrices
           .... setItemPrices();
    });
    // ...

}]);
```

Comment: I think that's the best way for how my model was set up. I'm experimenting with breaking it out into a model class with a computed price property to streamline the code, but I'm still quite new to Angular, so you've been a big help. Thanks!